# RunWorkerAsync close BackgroundWorker on complete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I have a Background worker that needs to be called multiple times based on the number of checkboxes checked - I have written this to get the checkbox values and put them into a `List`.

```
List repSelected = new List();
```

This is populated and then iterated over like so:

```
foreach (string rep in repSelected)
{
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(rep);
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
}
```

The async, DoWork code looks like this:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
string rep = e.Argument.ToString();

if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
else
{
    DirectoryExists(rep);
    ProcessRunner(rep); //Rars some large files - expensive
}
```

The process then runs WorkerComplete, the problem is when the process goes back to do the next iteration of the Worker it crashes out saying the worker is busy - even though the worker has returned it's WorkerCompleted status.

How can I make sure that the thread is closed before the next iteration of the loop?

NB: I had a conditional on the background worker containing `!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy()` but this (obviously) just skipped over the remaining iterations without execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to process each item in sequence, there is no reason to use a separate backgroundworker for each task. So it will be better to move the foreach loop into the DoWork method. But if you want to process all items in paralell, you need to create one background worker for each item.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was after, thanks! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to create a new background worker per item but still utilise the same code to-be-executed?

Comment: You can move the DoWork code into a separate method and use the rep value as parameter. But, in your code it seems that you are processing files, so if they are placed on a mechanical drive (not SSD), I think your code will perform much better if you process files in sequence. That is because you will avoid moving the disk head back and forth.

Comment: @HenkHolterman using 1 Backgroundworker with parallel.foreach will result in the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> If the background operation is already running, calling RunWorkerAsync again will raise an InvalidOperationException.

So you cannot use a `BackgroundWorker` to maintain a **queue** of tasks (and you push all tasks in sequence without waiting the one before to complete). You have different solutions for this, for example if you want to keep using the `BackgroundWorker` you may do this:

```
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(repSelected);
```

Then change your `DoWork` method like follow:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

foreach (string rep in (IEnumerable<string>)e.Argument)
{
    if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        DirectoryExists(rep);
        ProcessRunner(rep); //Rars some large files - expensive
    }
}
```

As alternative you may consider to change how you perform this task, for example using `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` or the `ThreadPool` (directly or indirectly, most parallel operations will be queued to the pool).

Answer (score 1):

Your foreach-code will trigger the work for all elements immediately. This is why you get the exception.

If you want to start the worker sequentially, you only can call RunWorkerAsync once at start and then for each WorkerComplete-event. But why not make the processing foreach in the worker-code?

Answer (score 1):

The BackgroundWorker is really busy, because when the first call of `backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(rep);`, it does not wait for anything, then the second, third,... call is invoked immediately.

You should create BackgroundWorker each call, then it will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

You may employ parallel.foreach and multiple backgroundworkers;

```
Parallel.ForEach(YourListofStrings,
                 (q) =>
                 {
                     BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
                     worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
                     worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
                     worker.RunWorkerAsync(q);
                 });
```

Comment: Good solution - But I will take Espen's advice and run sequentially to avoid thrashing the HDD. +1